# En tkinter, al agregar imagen .png a BUTTON pierdo la transparencia y se cambia a blanco. ¿Cómo puedo mantener la transparencia de la imagen?

Tags: python, imagen, tkinter, botón

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]#!/usr/bin/python

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-s

## LIBRERIAS

from tkinter import Tk,Frame,Label,Button
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

## EVENTO SALIR APP CON TECLA -ESC-

def close(event):
    root.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
    sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing

## ******************************************************* Script Principal ********************************************************

if **name**=="**main**":

## ESTADOS INICIALES

```
AnchoFrame = 600  #parametro de ancho del frame
AltoFrame  = 400
```

## INTERFAZ GRÁFICA

```
root = Tk()
ox = root.winfo_screenwidth()/2
oy = root.winfo_screenheight()/2[introducir la descripción de la imagen [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]aquí][1]

root.geometry("=%dx%d+%d+[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]%d" % (AnchoFrame, AltoFrame, (ox - (AnchoFrame/2)), (oy-(AltoFrame/2))) )
root.overrideredirect(1)                                #sacarle los bordes a la ventana                                                                                    #sin bordes
root.resizable(False,False)                             #no puede cambiar de tamaño
#root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.99)                     #Transparencia
root.config(bd=0)                                       #grosot borde
root.config(relief="flat", bg="black", borderwidth = 0) #stilo borde

miFrame=Frame(root, width=AnchoFrame, height=AltoFrame) #tamaño del frame
miFrame.config(relief="flat", bg="grey38")              #stilo de frame

ruta_img = Image.open("fondo.png")
ruta_img = ruta_img.resize((AnchoFrame,AltoFrame),Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ruta_img)
background = Label(image=image)                         #Fondo
background.pack()
miFrame.pack()                                          #empaquetado del frame

ruta_img_boton = Image.open("boton.png")
#ruta_img_boton = ruta_img_boton.resize((500,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ruta_img_boton)
BOTON = Button(image=image2,command=lambda:root.destroy(), relief="flat")
BOTON.place(x=140,y=280)
```

## EVENTO ESC

```
root.bind('<Escape>', close) #EVENTO DE LA TECLA ESC
```

## MAINLOOP

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: puedes revisar este enlace  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889265/how-create-button-with-png-background-in-tkinter

Comment: Gracias. No me sirve ese metodo.. Mi fondo no es unicolor... Por lo que agregar un bg a mi widget no soluciona mi problema