# PhotoImage no carga imagenes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Esta vez estoy haciendo una pequeño GUI en el que se muestran una serie de botones que contienen una imagen pero la susodicha no se muestra y es como si el botón no funcionara.

He intentado importar tkinter y luego importando PhotoImage asi nomas sin extito.

He importado tkinter as tk y luego colocando tk.PhotoImagen sin exito tambien.

Intente crear un modulo aparte con las imágenes pero me pedía crear un root primero y se complico un poco todo al no saber como inicializar con el primer root.

Y pues bueno, nada funciono.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

El codigo va algo asi:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import PhotoImage

def llamada():
    print("Papaya")

class AppSimple(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(PaginaGeneral)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class PaginaGeneral(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        imagen= tk.PhotoImage(file= "hola.gif")
        tituloPrograma= tk.Label(self, text= "PROGRAMA PRUEBA")
        tituloPrograma.pack()
        introduccionPrograma4= tk.Label(self, image= imagen).pack()

        botonSiguienteGeneral= tk.Button(self, text= "INICIO", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PaginaUno))
        botonSiguienteGeneral.pack()

class PaginaUno(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tituloGeneral= tk.Label(self, text= "SOY UN LABEL SUPREMO")
        tituloGeneral.grid(row=2, column=3)

        imagenUno= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c1.png")
        imagenDos= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c2.png")
        imagenTres= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c3.png")
        imagenCuatro= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c4.png")
        imagenCinco= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c5.png")

        botonUno= tk.Button(self, image= imagenUno, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=2)
        botonDos= tk.Button(self, image= imagenDos, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=3)
        botonTres= tk.Button(self, image= imagenTres, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=4)
        botonCuatro= tk.Button(self, image= imagenCuatro, command= llamada).grid(row=4, column=2)
        botonCinco= tk.Button(self, image= imagenCinco, command= llamada).grid(row=4, column=4)

class PaginaDos(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tituloGeneral= tk.Label(self, text= "SOY UN LABEL AUN MAS SUPREMO")
        tituloGeneral.grid(row=2, column=3)

        imagenUno= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c1.png")
        imagenDos= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c2.png")
        imagenTres= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c3.png")
        imagenCuatro= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c4.png")
        imagenCinco= tk.PhotoImage(file= "Imagenes\ejemplo\c5.png")

        llamada= funcion1()
        botonUno= tk.Button(self, image= imagenUno, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=2)
        botonDos= tk.Button(self, image= imagenDos, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=3)
        botonTres= tk.Button(self, image= imagenTres, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=4)
        botonCuatro= tk.Button(self, image= imagenCuatro, command= llamada).grid(row=4, column=2)
        botonCinco= tk.Button(self, image= imagenCinco, command= llamada).grid(row=4, column=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = AppSimple()
    app.mainloop()
```

Y se ve algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin entrar a mirar tu código (y por tanto es posible que tenga errores que no he visto) lo que sí me ha llamado la atención es que en las rutas a los ficheros usas el carácter \ que es especial dentro de las cadenas y te puede por tanto dar problemas. Quizás venga de ahí el que no cargue las imágenes. Puedes probar a: cambiar los \ por /, o duplicar cada \ (es decir, poner \\ donde había un \), o usar "cadenas raw" que se identifican porque llevan una r delante `r"imagenes\ejemplo\c5.png"`. Dentro de éstas cadenas raw usar \ no plantea problema.

Comment: Gracias por responder.

He resuelto la problemática de caracteres (de hecho me ayudaste a solucionar otros problemas no relacionados) pero sigue sin funcionalidad.

Se que mi problema es que la imagen no esta definida en el botón y el recolector de basura la elimina, hay soluciones aquí pero no las entiendo:

[Aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190553/en-tkinter-al-agregar-imagen-png-a-button-pierdo-la-transparencia-y-se-cambia)
[Aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162097/a%C3%B1adir-botones-con-im%C3%A1genes-de-forma-din%C3%A1mica-no-se-muestran-las-im%C3%A1genes)

Comment: @LogicaMiau Por favor evita colocar información irrelevante y repetitiva ya que no contribuyen a entender su problema, solo es ruido

Comment: Perdón @eyllanesc, ya medio la edite para una mejor comprension 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo la solución a tu problema. Como ya sabes, el problema se debe a que Python borra las variables. Entonces la solución está en que no sean borradas.
Por lo que vi, guardas el Frame creado dentro de tu class `AppSimple`, la cual a su vez guardas en una variable.
Por lo tanto, todo lo que guardas en AppSimple no se borra, incluyendo el frame.

Entonces, la solución sería guardar las imágenes dentro del frame que creas, como lo señalo en este fragmento modificado de tu código.

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage

def llamada():
    print("Papaya")

class AppSimple(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(PaginaGeneral)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class PaginaGeneral(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        #guardo la imagen dentro del frame
        self.imagen= tk.PhotoImage(file= "img1.png")

        tituloPrograma= tk.Label(self, text= "PROGRAMA PRUEBA")
        tituloPrograma.pack()
        introduccionPrograma4= tk.Label(self, image= self.imagen).pack()

        botonSiguienteGeneral= tk.Button(self, text= "INICIO", command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PaginaUno))
        botonSiguienteGeneral.pack()

class PaginaUno(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tituloGeneral= tk.Label(self, text= "SOY UN LABEL SUPREMO")
        tituloGeneral.grid(row=2, column=3)

        #guardo las imagenes dentro del Frame
        self.imagenUno= tk.PhotoImage(file= "img1.png")
        self.imagenDos= tk.PhotoImage(file= "img2.png")
        self.imagenTres= tk.PhotoImage(file= "img3.png")

        botonUno= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenUno, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=2)
        botonDos= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenDos, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=3)
        botonTres= tk.Button(self, image= self.imagenTres, command= llamada).grid(row=3, column=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = AppSimple()
    app.mainloop()
```

Ojalá te sirva y espero que hayas entendido mi explicación.

Comment: paps, solamente quería decirte que me funciono de maravilla. ¡Muchísimas gracias! tenia un montón de días con este problema y la solución resulto de lo mas simple pero no podía verla, gracias por abrirme los ojos. Se que no debo responder con un gracias así nomas pero realmente estoy agradecido, me llevo la llamada de atención con gusto con tal de que lo sepas:)

Comment: No somos tan diferentes, de nada, un placer ayudar c: aun asi es verdad que no deberiamos de hacer esto.